# How to set Scrollbar colour in flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a normal `ListView` which is wrapped by the `Scrollbar` class to produce a scrollbar when scrolling down. But I want to change the `Scrollbar` color to white since I have a dark background.

After exploring the `Scrollbar` class I can see that it uses the theme `highlightColor` as shown inside `scrollbar.dart`.

> _themeColor = theme.highlightColor.withOpacity(1.0);

Tried wrapping the `Scrollbar` in a `Theme` but still no luck.

Below is my code -

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
    highlightColor: Colors.white, //Does not work
  ),
  child: Scrollbar(
    child: ListView(
      //Normal ListView code
    ),
  ),
)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scrollbar.dart

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I did check this file already. I need a way to change the scrollbar fill color.

Comment: it should already adjust to a grayish-white itself when your background is dark

Comment: This solution is working for me. However, I used `copyWith` as `                                 Theme(data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(highlightColor: Colors.white), ...)`

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can use RawScrollbar instead and set the thumbColor to whatever color you like.

```dart
child: RawScrollbar(
  thumbColor: Colors.redAccent,
  radius: Radius.circular(20),
  thickness: 5,
  child: // scrollable widget
)
```

Comment: for newbies (me), answer above also works with child:  Scrollbar( ... )

Comment: No, because `Scrollbar` widget does not have `thumbColor` property

Answer (score 27):

I changed it like this.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        scrollbarTheme: ScrollbarThemeData().copyWith(
          thumbColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey[500]),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if this has an impact on performance?

Answer (score 17):

Scroll bar uses the highlight color.. so just add ur desired scrollbar color in the highlightColor inside Theme in MaterialApp and you are done.

```
MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        //main color
        primaryColor: const Color(0xffFFC600),
        //main font
        fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium',
        //swatch stretching
        primarySwatch: goldenThemeColor,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,

        splashColor:  const Color(0xffFFC600),

        //color for scrollbar
        highlightColor: Color(0xffffc600)

      ),

      routes: {
        '/' : (context) => SplashScreen(),
        ...
      }
      initialRoute: '/',
    )
```

Comment: What if you are using Scrollbar in a CupertinoApp?

Comment: It's more safe to add scrollbarTheme to your ThemeData class. Inside that class just override thumbColor.

Answer (score 14):

Flutter now provides scrollbarTheme you can use it to set global scroll bar theme and change the thumbColor property as shown below

```dart
ScrollbarThemeData(
  interactive: true,
  isAlwaysShown: true,
  radius: const Radius.circular(10.0),
  thumbColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
    DarkAppColors.primaryTextColor.withOpacity(0.4),
  ),
  thickness: MaterialStateProperty.all(5.0),
  minThumbLength: 100,
)
```

Comment: somehow my iOS simulator crash after adding this code, Lost Connection, only on iOS Simulator

Comment: Tks bro! If do like this way, we can more config both trackColor or trackColorBorder :D

Comment: can you complete code for edxample where is need to put the code `ScrollbarThemeData` more clear please .

Answer (score 0):

you could clone the file you linked and change the color inside your project, and then instead of using Scrollbar() use, for example, MyScrollBar(), the edited file you cloned

Comment: That won't be an optimal solution, since I would end up adding large amounts of code just to change a few lines. I wanted to know if there is way to directly set the color of the `Scrollbar`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer not to manually set a color to the scrollbar, as it doesn't behave the same way as the default one unless you set the colors for every material state. A solution that worked perfectly for me was to wrap the `ListView` in a `Theme` widget and set the `colorScheme` to one with a `Brightness.dark` brightness.

```dart
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark()),
  child: ListView(...),
)
```

Answer (score -2):

I fix this problem like this:
Just use ScrollbarTheme, and u can change thumbColor

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).